# Leg Bones "Freak Out' When Exported to FBX

Tags: animation, export, bones, baking, .fbx

I am animating an armature and everything is fine in the .blend file, however when I export to an fbx the upper leg bones sometimes rotate erratically for a few frames. Below are two images: the first one is the .blend file and the second one is the .fbx file. Both are on frame 96. Being somewhat a novice at rigging I am very lost on what the problem could be. I am very happy to provide additional info!

[image]

[image]

The upper leg bone is controlled by a an inverse kinematics bone, so there is no manual movement of it at all. The position of the bone does not change, only it's rotation.
[image]

Comment: What was it's original position

Comment: The upper leg bone is controlled by a an inverse kinematics bone, so there is no manual movement of it at all. The position of the bone does not change, only it's rotation. (I updated the post to show an image of this)